# matplot:problem displaying labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to graph multiple lines in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

I have used to the label function but it is not displaying it.

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot

adani = pd.read_csv(r'F:\Pycharm_projects\pytorch_bliztz\nifty50-stock-market-data\ADANIPORTS.csv')
asianpaint = pd.read_csv(r'F:\Pycharm_projects\pytorch_bliztz\nifty50-stock-market-data\ASIANPAINT.csv')
adani1 = adani.High
asian_paint = asianpaint.High
plt.plot(asian_paint, label="asian_paint")
plt.plot(adani1, label='adaini1')

plt.show()
```

Here is my image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following command after plotting

```
plt.legend()
```